# Google Cloud MissingSecurityHeader error

Tags: authentication, cloud, google-cloud-storage

While there is a thread about this problem on Google's FAQ, it seems like there are only two answers that have satisfied other users.  I'm certain there is no proxy on my network and I'm pretty sure I've configured boto as I see credentials in the request.

Here's the capture from gsutil:

/// Output sanitized

```
Creating gs://64/...
DEBUG:boto:path=/64/
DEBUG:boto:auth_path=/64/
DEBUG:boto:Method: PUT
DEBUG:boto:Path: /64/
DEBUG:boto:Data: <CreateBucketConfiguration><LocationConstraint>US</LocationConstraint></\
CreateBucketConfiguration>
DEBUG:boto:Headers: {'x-goog-api-version': '2'}
DEBUG:boto:Host: storage.googleapis.com
DEBUG:boto:Params: {}
DEBUG:boto:establishing HTTPS connection: host=storage.googleapis.com, kwargs={'timeout':\
 70}
DEBUG:boto:Token: None
DEBUG:oauth2_client:GetAccessToken: checking cache for key dc3
DEBUG:oauth2_client:FileSystemTokenCache.GetToken: key=dc3 present (cache_file=/tmp/o\
auth2_client-tokencache.1000.dc3)
DEBUG:oauth2_client:GetAccessToken: token from cache: AccessToken(token=ya29, expiry=2\
013-07-19 21:05:51.136103Z)
DEBUG:boto:wrapping ssl socket; CA certificate file=.../gsutil/third_party/boto/boto/cace\
rts/cacerts.txt
DEBUG:boto:validating server certificate: hostname=storage.googleapis.com, certificate ho\
sts=['*.googleusercontent.com', '*.blogspot.com', '*.bp.blogspot.com', '*.commondatastora\
ge.googleapis.com', '*.doubleclickusercontent.com', '*.ggpht.com', '*.googledrive.com', '\
*.googlesyndication.com', '*.storage.googleapis.com', 'blogspot.com', 'bp.blogspot.com', \
'commondatastorage.googleapis.com', 'doubleclickusercontent.com', 'ggpht.com', 'googledri\
ve.com', 'googleusercontent.com', 'static.panoramio.com.storage.googleapis.com', 'storage\
.googleapis.com']
GSResponseError: status=400, code=MissingSecurityHeader, reason=Bad Request, detail=A non\
empty x-goog-project-id header is required for this request.
send: 'PUT /64/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: storage.googleapis.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: iden\
tity\r\nContent-Length: 98\r\nx-goog-api-version: 2\r\nAuthorization: Bearer ya29\r\nU\
ser-Agent: Boto/2.9.7 (linux2)\r\n\r\n<CreateBucketConfiguration><LocationConstraint>US</\
LocationConstraint></CreateBucketConfiguration>'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
header: Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8^M
header: Content-Length: 232^M
header: Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2013 20:44:24 GMT^M
header: Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 12 2013 17:12:36 (1373674356)^M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might not have a `default_project_id` specified in your `.boto` file.

It should look something like this:

```
[GSUtil]
default_project_id = 1234567890
```

Alternatively, you can pass the `-p` option to the `gsutil mb` command to manually specify a project. From the [gsutil mb](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mb) documentation:

```
-p proj_id  Specifies the project ID under which to create the bucket.
```

Comment: Sending a project ID along with the request did the trick.

I see that I missed the prompt for the project ID after navigating to the console, http://code.google.com/apis/console.